# Get only the elements that exist in each array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array of arrays, for example

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
            [4] => 6
            [5] => 16
            [6] => 25
            [7] => 26
            [8] => 27
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 6
        )

)
```

What I need to do is reduce that to a single array, containing only the elements which are in each of the outer arrays, so for the above example, the elements 3 and 6. I've completely hit a wall trying to think how I'd even begin to do this. Can someone point me in the right direction on how I can do this?

Comment: Have you looked at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple as that:

```
$result = call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $array);
```

where `$array` is your "whole" array.

Comment: Wow, such a simple solution! Thanks :). Is there anywhere I can look to see the actual code behind `array_intersect`? I'm curious to how it actually works.

Comment: Sure. [Here you go](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/ext/standard/array.c#php_array_intersect)